# PHP regexping the string (extracting)

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to get a substring (see examples, bold part) from the string. All strings begin with "input" followed by 2 underscores with some (1 to 7) random chars between. Thank you!

Examples:

input_7ax8_**SOME_INFO**

input_3f0max2_**SOME_OTHER_INFO**

input_k_**ANOTHERINFO-any-chars-possible:0123456789**

Comment: Is the text you provided HTML format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the detection of "non underscore" + "underscore" times 2 and fetching everything that comes after that you can get the result you ask.

The ?: is meant for not returning the result of the parts with underscores because the () are needed to combine it together.

```
$input = 'input_k_ANOTHERINFO-any-chars-possible:0123456789';
preg_match( '~^(?:[^_]+_){2}(.*)$~', $input, $match );
var_export($match);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need `explode` and its third param :

```
<?php
$input = 'input_7ax8_SOME_INFO';
$input = explode("_",$input,2); // Split 2 times
$input[2] = '<b>'.$input[2].'</b>'; // Make the rest of the string bold
$input = implode("_",$input); // re joining

echo $input;
?>
```

Comment: What if the third param contains underscore ?

Comment: The request was for using a regex and the bold part was just to mark what is needed if I interpet the question correctly.

Comment: The third param can only contains an integer value

Comment: @moorscode : as long as it could helps the OP,, why not ?

Comment: @MichaelAntonio : I don't think so, look : "ANOTHERINFO-any-chars-possible:0123456789"

Comment: @MichaelAntonio because it is not the question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer "Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for?"

Comment: @MateoBarahona : okay maybe you're right. Mateo. I just got confused about what the asker want to

Comment: @MichaelAntonio : Maybe because it was not so clear... Anyway, I think your approach is nice, you can implode what you get after second index, and it will work !

Comment: @MateoBarahona : mmm yeah. hope it could helps him xD